# Rails 4: Slashes from to_param slug get escaped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to get my url paths to look something like this in my Rails 4.1.7 app:

```
http://localhost:3000/section/YYYY/MM/DD/article-title-goes-here
```

To make this work, I've created a migration:

```
rails g migration add_slug_to_articles slug:string:uniq
rake db:migrate
```

And then I added the following in my article.rb model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    slug
  end
end
```

I updated all the entries in my database with:

```
article.update(:slug => [article.section.downcase, article.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"), article.title.parameterize].join('/'))
```

But now when I click on links, all the slashes **/** are getting escaped with **%2F**:

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/section%2F2014%2F11%2F10%2Farticle-title-goes-here
```

I have been looking around and it seems that one option is to monkeypatch ActionDispatch but it seems a little hardcore for me, for something that imo is pretty common. Isn't there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to define custom non-restful routes for you purposes.
Guides describe very well how to do it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes

Such approach will give you possibility to filter articles via section, date and title.

On the other side your current approach looks like a hack.

Comment: Apologies for the ignorance but I can't seem to understand how I'd set the date from routing in the way you showed... would you please explain?

Comment: something like this: get 'articles/:section/:year/:month/:day/:title', to: 'articles#show'

Comment: This means I always need to pass 5 params to any link_to method that references articles, correct?

Comment: you can define your own helper, my_article_path(article), inside of which you will incapsulate complex url generation. In such case you will not pass all 5 params each time

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in the following way:

```
s = /section1|section2|section3|section4/
y = /\d{4}/
m = /\d{2}/

resources :articles, except: [:index, :show]
resources :articles, only: [:index, :show], path: '/:section/:year/:month', constraints: {:section => s, :year => y, month: m, slug: /[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/}

get ':section/:year/:month', to: 'articles#by_month', as: :month, constraints: {section: s, year: y, month: m}
get ':section/:year', to: 'articles#by_year', as: :year, constraints: {section: s, year: y}
get ':section', to: 'articles#by_section', as: :section, constraints: {section: s}
```

Then in my articles_controller.rb I have

```
def by_section
  ..
end

def by_year
  ..
end

def by_month
  ..
end

def show
  @article = Article.find_by_slug params[:slug]
end
```

The only really annoying thing is that I need to pass around a bunch of params with each path in the views:

```
<%= link_to @article.title, article_path(@article.section, @article.created_at.year, @article.created_at.month, @article.slug, @article.id) %>
```